# Docker httpd doesn't match a volume

Tags: docker, apache, volumes

I pulled httpd: docker pull httpd.

When I started the container:

```
docker run --name httpd --rm -p 80:80 -v $(pwd)/htdocs:/htdocs -d httpd
```

I see the original `index.html` page even if in my htdocs I put my personal index page.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2):

You're mounting the directory on `/htdocs`, but that's not where Apache is looking for files. If you examine the Apache configuration in the `httpd` image, `DocumentRoot` points at `/usr/local/apache2/htdocs`:

```
root@6eaea8a511b9:/usr/local/apache2# grep DocumentRoot conf/httpd.conf
# DocumentRoot: The directory out of which you will serve your
DocumentRoot "/usr/local/apache2/htdocs"
```

So your command line needs to be:

```
docker run --name httpd --rm -p 80:80 -v $(pwd)/htdocs:/usr/local/apache2/htdocs -d httpd
```

Comment: Thanks I forget that the container when executed doesn't launch bash on root but on configured dir.